# How can I make a jQuery UI buttonset fluid?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a very simple web app (http://www.tntech.edu/cafe-menu.php) that is being iframed into a mobile app built by ATT. The buttons are different sizes on different phones and I need to figure out how to make them fluid.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean they're different sizes for different screen resolutions?  If so, use % sizes instead of px sizes.

Comment: I set font-size to 125% but it didn't work as expected so I posted here.

Comment: Is it the buttons or the text that you want to be the same on all devices?  If it's the buttons then you need to set the width and height using % values.

Comment: might need to use a [css reset](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+reset) to get matching sizes, looks like you're using `em` which should work after a reset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to set the width on label.ui-button to a percent and then it worked. Thanks guys!